# How does a method in a winform listen to an event/delegate in App_Code, and not get a null event?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

Scenario -

Program opens a winForm.  User enters info, clicks Start button.  Action transfers to code in App_Code.Model.  When that code finishes, code behind the winForm needs to display updated information.  App_Code.Model shouldn't know about the winForm.  The winForm in this case has a button btnStart and a textbox tbInput.

But when the event is raised, it is null, so I am doing something wrong.  Note, this is not about events raised from winForms userControls, I am aware there is a lot of information online about that.

App_Code.Model
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

```
namespace EventsTest.App_Code.Model
{
    public delegate void TableViewChangeHandler(object sender, HandChangedEventArgs e);

    public class HandChangedEventArgs : EventArgs{
        public int HandNum { get; set; }
        public int PlayerNum { get; set; }
        public HandChangedEventArgs(int handNum, int playerNum){
            HandNum = handNum;
            PlayerNum = playerNum;
        }
    }
    public class Game{
        public event TableViewChangeHandler TableViewChanged;
        public void PrepareGame(){
            int value = -1;
            if (TableViewChanged != null)
                TableViewChanged(this, new HandChangedEventArgs(value, 0));
            else
                value = 2;//used to set toggle to catch debugger
        }
    }
}
```

code  behind form
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using EventsTest.App_Code.Model;

```
namespace EventsTest
{
    public partial class testForm : Form{
        public testForm(){
            InitializeComponent();
            Game myGame = new Game();
            myGame.TableViewChanged += this.HandleTableViewChange;
        }
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Game myGame = new Game();
            myGame.PrepareGame();
        }
        public void HandleTableViewChange(object sender, HandChangedEventArgs e){
            this.tbInput.Text = "Raised";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a null? If call PrepareGame() the value will always == 2?

Comment: TableViewChanged is always null, the 'else' should never execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I understand. You have two instances of Game class:

1. Is in ctor of the form and subscribes to the event.
2. Is in btnStart_Click method which doesn't subscribe to event and call PrepareGame(), so you don't recieve event notification.

MOve your event subaceiption code to button click handler and you done.